# Html template won't render from Flask. SystemError: error return without exception set

Tags: python, html, flask

This really has me scratching my head. I'm using geolocation to get a user's coordinates. Then I'm taking the lat and lng and sending them to my "/restaurant_list" route and creating an object: "r_list".

```
@app.route('/user_location', methods=["POST"])
def user_location():
    coords = request.get_json()
    lat = str(coords['location']['lat'])
    lng = str(coords['location']['lng'])
    print(lat, lng)
    return redirect(url_for('restaurant_list_page', lat=lat, lng=lng))
```

So far, so good. The list of results is returned and then split in half. The two halves, along with their lengths, are being passed to "restaurant_list.html" for processing on the page.

When I run PyCharm to debug it line by line, everything goes perfect right up until the very last line:

```
@app.route('/restaurant_list/<lat>/<lng>')
def restaurant_list_page(lat, lng):
    try:
        # Create RestaurantList object using 3 arguments
        r_list = RestaurantList(lat, lng, '33')

        # Return list of results
        results = r_list.results

        if len(results) % 2 == 0:                   # Check if list is odd or even and split in half
            top = results[:(len(results) // 2)]
            bottom = results[(len(results) // 2):]
            toplen = len(top)
            botlen = len(bottom)
            return render_template("restaurant_list.html", top=top, toplen=toplen, bot=bottom, botlen=botlen)
    except Exception:
        return render_template("main.html")
```

From here it just seems to crash. The html template never renders. I see errors like this in the console:

```
File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\urls.py", line 462, in <genexpr>
    if not rest or any(c not in s("0123456789") for c in rest):
SystemError: error return without exception set
Exception ignored in: <generator object url_parse.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002ECE5F7F0C8>
```

I have no idea what this is telling me. Any help?

What's even more bizarre is the console will print the GET request when it fails, and if I copy and paste the URL into the browser, it will load up and function as intended...

```
GET /restaurant_list/27.2883712/-82.4827904 HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Comment: where do you have `except:` ?

Comment: please provide an MVCE

Comment: I have edited to show the except: but it's not really relevant for this because it's never being triggered. The code is crashing somewhere behind the scenes in Flask.

Comment: is this full Traceback ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `len(results) % 2 == 0` is false?  In that case, the function returns nothing at all.  Perhaps that is the issue.